# Cannot resolve symbol 'OnClickListener' - View.OnClickListener

Tags: android

I'm working on Android buttons but its giving me an error cannot resolve the symbol, I'm using the correct syntax but why it gives me an error

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.viewb);
    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, View.class));
        }
    });

    Button b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.adminb);
    b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Admin.class));
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: Use `Ctrl+Enter` in Android Studio to import the required class. Alternatively, use this command `import android.view.View;` in the imports list

Comment: I did that, but it causes my app to stop.

Comment: A runtime exception is different than a compile time exception. As it is, your question is missing an import. If your app stops, then there's something else wrong with your code

Comment: For example  `View.class` is not an Activity. It cannot be started

Comment: What about `Clean Project` and `Rebuild Project` ??? Your code is fine !!!

Answer (score -2):

You are wrong with `View.OnClickListener`
it should be like

```
b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
          startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Admin.class));
        }
    });
```

and you forgot the Override annotation

Comment: None of that is wrong. `OnClickListener` **is** `View.OnClickListener`

Comment: then i dont see any problem there